# No resources found in Jhipster jar

Tags: spring-boot, jar, jhipster

I have a Jhipster Spring Boot project with version:

- Java: 1.8
- Jhipster: 3.0.3
- Spring Boot: 2.1.6.RELEASE

It worked well with WAR package. I changed WAR to JAR package, it can run in IntelliJ, but with command line `java -jar myproject.jar` the resources files can't be found at run time.

How to get resources files in Jhipster jar file?

Here are the changes in the pom.xml:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

...

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
                <include>config/*.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
...
</resources>
...
</build>
```

In a Java file, I use DefaultResourceLoader to load resources:

```
DefaultResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/");
try(
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
            br.lines().forEach(fileName -> {
                LOGGER.info("Update config: {}", fileName);
```

...
On command line mode, the info "Update config: xxx" is never logged.

The resources files are in the directory:
`${project.basedir}/src/main/resources`

I also tried to add resources with copy-resources in the pom, but I couldn't get resources files.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-resources</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>config/*.yml</include>
                                            <include>**/*.json</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                  </resources>
                                </execution>
                              </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

**Update**
As mentioned by @GaëlMarziou, I found resources in .jar.original. So the problem is in my Java code.
To list all resource files in a directory in the jar, I should use Resource[]. Here is the corrected code:

```
@Value("classpath:config/*")
private Resource[] configFiles;
    ...
Arrays.stream(configFiles).map(file -> file.getFilename()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: When you say they are not in the jar, did you confirm by unzipping it or by error at runtime? What does maven log says? BTW your spring boot version is 3 years old and so vulnerable, you should consider updating it.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thank you for your advice, I found resources in .jar.original
I fixed the problem in Java, to list all resources in a directory, I should use Resource[], I update my post.